# Highcharts Gantt - Show Tooltip on Dependency Path Hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

I'm trying to figure out an approach to add hover-over tooltips on the `Highcharts Gantt` dependency pathway; but am not sure the best approach as there doesn't seem to be a native config property to interact with the dependency pathways and endpoints.

I'm starting with the approach of binding a `mouseenter` event on the rendered `.highcharts-point-connecting-path` class; however, the returned object doesn't appear to have any identifying `data` attributes to help tie the `mouseenter` object to an object that holds the tooltip data.

```
$('#gchart-container').on('mouseenter','.highcharts-point-connecting-path',function(event) {
    console.log( this );
});

// returns
// <path fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#3ABFDA" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point-connecting-path highcharts-color-4" d="M 17.5 125.5 L 30.5 125.5 L 30.5 100.5 L 30.5 100.5 L 30.5 25.5 L 17.5 25.5"></path>
```

Since I already have all the original series data stored in my `$data` object, if there was a way to add custom data properties to the series dependency that would show on the HTML node, then this solution would work.  E.g. adding a custom attribute like `data-series-id` or something:

```
// <path fill="none" data-series-id="aa33233dd" opacity="1" stroke="#3ABFDA" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point-connecting-path high..... blah blah blah"></path>
```

Then `$data['aa33233dd']` could be accessed to get the appropriate info... in theory.

Any ideas? Or is there a way better approach to do this?

Comment: If the above can't necessary be achieved - then perhaps simply updating the `strokeWidth` of the `path` object on `mouseover` would work; but `this` doesn't have a `setAttribute` function - so what is the appropriate way to update Highcharts SVG lines and redraw (if necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a better approach will be to create this custom functionality inside the load callback, where you can have access to the whole chart.

Here is my guideline: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1v0oquaf/

Code:

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
          chart.pathfinder.connections[0].pathfinder.group.element.onmouseover = function() {
            console.log(chart)
          }
        }, 100)
      }
    }
  },
```

I use the setTimeout because it seems that the load function triggers before the path has been rendering.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/chart.events.load

Comment: is `load() {` a typo? should it be `load: {` ?

Comment: Also - this is a great solution for enabling the event; however, after looking into the available event objects it still doesn't seem there is a way to link the `mouseenter` `element` to a `series.data` `object` - all that is returned from this solution is the original `<path...` object in my OP

Comment: load is a function callback, could be `load: function() {}`

Comment: Could you reproduce a demo with your attempt with sample data? And describe what do you want to display in the tooltip?